# Class for key.serializer could not be found

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, kafka-producer-api, serialization

I am sending Array of JSON data to Kafka topic using Spring boot Application, but getting the following error:

```
error :org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Invalid value 
org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer; for 
configuration key.serializer: Class 
org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer; could not be found.
```

I have tried to change serialization configuration to this:

```
props.put("key.serializer",  org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer;");
props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer;");
```

to

```
props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer;");
props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer;");
```

Configuration file and Service File code:

```
@Configuration
public class KafkaProducerConfig {

@Bean

private static ProducerFactory<String, String> producerConfig() {

            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
            props.put("acks", "all");
            props.put("retries", 0);
            props.put("batch.size", 16384);
            props.put("linger.ms", 1);
            props.put("buffer.memory", 33554432);
            props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer;");
            props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer;");

            // The following properties are used by LiKafkaProducerImpl
            props.put("large.message.enabled", "true");
            props.put("max.message.segment.bytes", 1000 * 1024);
            props.put("segment.serializer", DefaultSegmentSerializer.class.getName());

            props.put("auditor.class", LoggingAuditor.class.getName());

            return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory(props);
        }
}

@Service
public class KafkaSender {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(KafkaSender.class);

    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate;

    @Value("${kafka.topic.name}")
    private String topicName;

    public void sendData(List<Student> student) {

        System.out.println("Inside Student"+ student.toString());
        System.out.println("Inside Student"+ student);

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Map<String, Object> headers = new HashMap<>();
        headers.put(KafkaHeaders.TOPIC, topicName);     

        System.out.println("\nStudent=  " + headers);

        // Construct a JSONObject from a Map.
        JSONObject HeaderObject = new JSONObject(headers);
        System.out.println("\nUsing new JSONObject() ==> " + HeaderObject);
        final String record = HeaderObject.toString();

        final int recordSize = record.length();

        kafkaTemplate.send(new GenericMessage<>(student, headers));

        LOGGER.info("Data - " + student + " sent to Kafka Topic - " + topicName);
    }
}
```

POST json:

[{
        "studentId": "Q45678123",
        "firstName": "abc",
        "lastName": "xyz",
        "age": "12",
        "address": {
          "apartment": "apt 123",
          "street": "street Info",
          "state": "state",
          "city": "city",
          "postCode": "12345"
        }
    },
    {
        "studentId": "Q45678123",
        "firstName": "abc",
        "lastName": "xyz",
        "age": "12",
        "address": {
          "apartment": "apt 123",
          "street": "street Info",
          "state": "state",
          "city": "city",
          "postCode": "12345"
        }
    }
 ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the semicolon from the end of the values

```
props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer");
```

Or you could use the `class.getName()` method like you did for the segment serializer, which I would suggest is safer because then it guarantees that the serializer you want is available at compile time

Comment: thanks for the answer. i tried it but getting following error:

org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Can't convert value of class java.util.ArrayList to class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer specified in value.serializer

Comment: You need to actually send a string, not a list... `GenericMessage<>(student.toString()`

Comment: Note: sending a list of data is not recommended, and individual objects won't arrive in the topic. You'll end up with one message containing the entire list. If that's not expected, you need a loop

Comment: Thanks for help. it worked. now working on consumer side. but in consumer getting following error-org.springframework.kafka.listener.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener method could not be invoked with the incoming message

I changed Deserializer value to String.

Comment: I'd suggest creating a new post with your new code since I've solved your initial error